# How to get a Kivy app on Android to access the Internet

Tags: python, android, permissions, kivy, buildozer

I have a simple Kivy app to try out a clickable link opening a Web site. The code is:

```
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import webbrowser

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        ref = '[ref=https://kivy.org/doc/stable/]' + 'Kivy documentation' + '[/ref]'
        link = Label(text=ref, markup=True, on_ref_press=self.OpenLink)
        return link

    def OpenLink(self, label, ref):
        webbrowser.open(ref)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

When I run this app in the Kivy Launcher on Android, tapping the link works and opens the url in the browser. However, when I run the compiled app nothing happens when I tap the link.

In the buildozer.spec file I have:

`android.permissions = INTERNET`

According to all information I have been able to find, this is all I should need. What else am I missing?

I have tried logging the app using `adb logcat` but I can't see anything relating to the problem.

Comment: Try importing the `android` module, this is probably necessary to set up a webbrowser provider for android.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've tried that, but now the app crashes. Again there's nothing obvious in the log, however, I find the logging to be arcane as I am not an advanced android programmer. I suspect this is on the right track, though, so I will look more into the android module.

Comment: Ah, there it is in the log: 'ImportError: No module named android'